# format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float*’, but argument 2 has type ‘float (*)[(((sizetype)

Tags: c

im so confused, i know this program is not right at all, but don't know hot to fix it..

```
 #include <stdio.h>

  int main ()
 {
    int distance;
    float avg_speed;

    printf ("Enter the race distance (m): ");
    scanf ("%d", &distance);

    int Num_lanes;

    printf ("Enter number of lanes in use:");
    scanf ("%d", &Num_lanes);

    float Finish_times[Num_lanes];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Num_lanes; i++)
    {
    printf ("Enter finish time for lane %d (sec): ", i + 1);
    scanf ("%f", &(Finish_times));
    }

    int Worst_time = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Num_lanes; i++)
    {
    if (Finish_times[i] < Worst_time)
    {
     Worst_time = Finish_times[i];
     }
     }

     avg_speed = (distance / 1000) / (Worst_time / 3600);

     printf ("Lane wins in %d seconds, with an average speed of %f km/h",
     Worst_time, avg_speed);

     return 0
     }
```

if anyone could please guide me a little on some mistakes so i can improve, i will be thankful

Comment: `&(Finish_times)` --> `&Finish_times[i]`

Comment: `Finish_times[i] < Worst_time` ??

Comment: `1000` --> `1000.` , `3600` --> `3600.`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
scanf ("%f", &(Finish_times));
```

is wrong, it passes the address of the entire array each time. Instead, what you meant was "scan this into the `i`:th element", so you need to provide the address to the i:th element:

```
scanf ("%f", &Finish_times[i]);
```

Also, please note that if you're going to loop over `n` numbers to compute the min and the average, you generally don't need to store the numbers themselves. Just keep a running min and a running sum, and divide the latter by `n` once you're done. Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create array using dynamic memory allocation i.e. using `malloc()` or `calloc()` functions  Or you should define array elements at compile time i.e. while writing the code, decide array size. 
Second thing, while reading into a array you should use subscript operator ( [ ] ) with array name like this:

```
scanf ("%f", &Finish_times[i])
```